# editable form ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Video with 'id'=undefined)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ruby-on-rails, react-redux

I'm trying create a form in which a user can edit an existing video title and description. When sending PATCH request I get the following error. The parameters are reading the correct video id but in the wrong place. What do I need to modify for it to work?

[image]

edit form

```
class Edit extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            video_id: this.props.match.params.id,
            video_title: "",
            video_description: "",
        }
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    update(field) {
        return (e) => {
            this.setState({
                [field]: e.currentTarget.value
            })
        }
    }   

    handleSubmit() {
        // debugger
        this.props.updateVideo(this.state.video_id)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="edit-container">
                <form className="edit-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label>
                        <input 
                            type="text"
                            value={this.state.video_title}
                            placeholder="Your video's title"
                            onChange={this.update("video_title")}
                        />
                        <div>{this.state.video_title}</div>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input 
                            type="textarea"
                            value={this.state.video_description}
                            placeholder="Your video's description"
                            onChange={this.update("video_description")}
                        />  
                    </label>
                    <button>Edit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Edit;
```

edit container

```
import { connect } from  'react-redux';
import Edit from './edit';
import { fetchVideo, updateVideo } from '../../actions/video_actions';

const mSTP = ( state, ownProps ) => {
    
    return {
        // video: state.entities.videos[state.session.id],
        video: state.entities.videos[ownProps.match.params.id],
        // errors: state.errors
    }
};

const mDTP = dispatch => ({
    fetchVideo: videoId => dispatch(fetchVideo(videoId)),
    updateVideo: video => dispatch(updateVideo(video)),
});

export default connect(mSTP, mDTP)(Edit);
```

video api util

```
export const updateVideo = video => {
    return $.ajax({
        method: 'patch',
        url: `api/videos/${video.id}`,
        data: { video }
    })
}
```

video controller

```
   def update
        @video = Video.find(params[:id])
        if @video.update(video_params)
            render :show
        else
            render json: @video.errors.full_messages, status: 422
        end
    end

  
    def video_params 
        params.require(:video).permit(:video_title, :video_description, :owner_id, :video_url)
    end
```

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  root to: 'static_pages#root'

  namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
    resources :users, only: [:create, :index]
    resource :session, only: [:create, :destroy]
    resources :videos
  end

end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In handleSubmit you are passing the video_id to the updateVideo function:

```
handleSubmit() {
    // debugger
    this.props.updateVideo(this.state.video_id)
}
```

but your updateVideo function is expecting a video object:

```
export const updateVideo = video => {
    return $.ajax({
        method: 'patch',
        url: `api/videos/${video.id}`,
        data: { video }
    })
}
```

so you are getting undefined from `video.id`.

Comment: i changed handleSubmit to this.props.updateVideo(this.props.video) so it is an object. On submit it rolls back. Please see the screenshot attached

Comment: This is related to ActiveStorage.  If you are not trying to update the image in your model then I'd remove the video_url parameter to see if that works.

Comment: if i get rid of the url from video_params the upload stops working correctly and the video is not updated either

Comment: It might be worth either updating your question or creating a new one with your new problem.